# Automotive: how to safely connect the car's power grid to the input of an intelligent switch?

Tags: automotive

I have an intelligent switch. Let's take [this one](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS117-DS-v01_04-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30433a747525013abff8302d549c) as an example - it's the one I'm plan on using, unless I find a better one. What I need to do is drive it by the voltage from the car's power grid. There are two complications here:

1. I'd like to get 3.5-5 volts at the input of the switch, but I have no other voltage source to clamp the input to with a diode.
2. Whatever schematic you suggest must withstand voltage pulses up to at least 60V (better yet - 100), and keep in mind the pulses may have reverse polarity as well.

What are the simplest solutions you can think of?

I've been thinking along the lines of a high-resistance voltage divider + a suppressor diode or a Zener diode. But I have no idea if it will work, let alone - work reliably. Please keep in mind I'm not an electrical engineer, and don't beat me up if I ask how your solution works.

Comment: There is a schematic button on the editor toolbar. "I'd like to get 3.5-5 volts at the input of the switch". What does this mean?

Comment: @transistor: what would you like me to draw, a 3-pole? I have a 12-15 V source with harsh spikes, and I need to get stable and filtered 3.5-5 V low-current voltage from it.

Comment: The schematic would show the relationship between the battery, the intelligent switch, the load and whatever is triggering the intelligent switch. Question 1 is just asking how to generate 3.5 - 5 V and a linear voltage regulator would do that. The HITFET BTS 117 you referenced will accept up to 10 V on its control input so I don't understand what the 3.5 - 5 V is about.

Comment: 1. The battery becomes irrelevant once the engine is running and alternator spinning. There's no battery, there's a noisy voltage source with floating output. 2. I thought of a voltage regulator, but will it withstand the interference I'm trying to shield the switch from? Do you know any automotive-grade voltage regulator? If you do, that'd certainly do the trick. 3. I see no need to approach the maximum ratings. If 10 V is max and 2.5 is the maximum threshold voltage, then 5 V sounds about right to me.

Comment: So it's not about the switch in any way, but about protecting the load, is it?

Comment: Searching for "automotive transient protection" should give you a lot of valuable information and examples.

Comment: @HannoBinder: it's about protecting the *input of the switch*. The load is, luckily for me, protected already, else I'd have another ton of problems on my hands. And thanks for the search query hint! I tried searching some variations, but could never find the right term to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?
[image: Switch Circuit]
**Signal** can come from any 12V(nominal, unregulated) circuit in the vehicle.
**Vpos** can also come from any 12V(nominal) circuit capable of powering your load.

The zener diodes (marked 16v) protect by grounding overvolate spike & "freewheeling" negV transients while the regular/switching diodes block negV transients from your switch/load.

The 10K and 5K5 resistors form a (5.5/15.5) voltage divider to drive your input pin.

Comment: In principle - yes, this is it, but I have a couple questions.

Comment: 1. Won't the input suppressor be better placed AFTER the divider? Then the resistor will limit the current flowing through it when the voltage exceeds the limit.

Comment: 2. The symbol that you used for the `16v` diodes is a "transil", or a suppressor diode - not a Zener diode. Which, to the best of my knowledge, is actually more fitting here than a Zener. But, how will it work in this circuit? As far as I can see, any voltage spike will cause the diode to open, effectively creating a short circuit and possibly blowing a fuse (the whole circuit will be fuse-protected). It might be the less evil, but I would like to preserve my fuses, too, if possible. Also, I think I don't need to protect the load, just the input, as the switch is "fully protected" itself.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe The transistors marked 16v are _supposed_ to be zeners (sorry, that's a fault in my diagramming software on my phone). A zener diode protects from overvoltage spikes by "collapsing" reliably at a preset voltage (16v, in this case) applied to the diode in _reverse_, effectively "clipping" any voltages that would otherwise go over the zener's set voltage. -- As for the load protection diodes (top-right corner), if you trust your switch's internal "full protection" you can remove them without affecting anything else.

Comment: Thanks. If those are Zeners then I should certainly remove the top one because no Zener can handle 3 amps. Besides, my load is protected, and I trust the switch's protection as well.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fexTpL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Half-supply divider.*

- R1 and R2 provide a potential divider with the junction being half supply. This will vary between 6 to 7 volts on battery or alternator. This is well below the 10 V maximum input of the BTS117.
- C1 forms a filter to stabilise the voltage and absorb any transients.
- Current, I, through R1 and R2 is given by \$I = \frac {V}{R} = \frac {12}{20,000} = 0.6 mA\$.

[image: BTS117 datasheet extract]

*Figure 2. Extract from [BTS117 datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BTS117-DS-v01_04-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30433a747525013abff8302d549c).*

- **Normal operation**: The datasheet shows that normal 'on' current on the input is typically 30 µA. This is 1/20th of the current through R1 so the voltage on C1 won't drop dramatically.
- **Current limit operation**: If the device goes into current limit this is signalled on the control-pin (rather cleverly) by increasing the input current to 120 µA. This is 1/5th of the 600 µA passing through R1 so the voltage on C1 will drop by about a fifth. It will still be above the 'on' threshold.
- **Thermal shutdown**: If the device goes into thermal shutdown the input current will increase to 2200 µA (2.2 mA). The most R1 can supply will be about 1 - 1.2 mA so I'm not clear what will happen at this point.

---

Update: R1 - C1 will have a time constant given by \$\tau = R \cdot C\$. I've increased C1 to 10 µF so that the time constant becomes \$ \tau = 10~kΩ\cdot 10~µF = 100~ms\$. That should be plenty for typical transients.

Seeing as you have raised the point about internal resistance, I've added C2 to bypass any really high frequency noise that gets through.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was wondering what those "current limitation" and "thermal shutdown" currents were, and you explained it! Do you trust the capacitor to reliably filter transients, though? Do you have a recommendation on the type of the capacitor (in regards to its internal resistance, for example)? Shouldn't I at least add a serial input diode before the voltage divider?

Comment: The datasheet shows how to detect current limitation and thermal shutdown by measuring the voltage drop on the input feed resistor using an analog input pin on a micro. I've updated the answer to address your capacitor questions. If you mean a diode pointing down in series with R1, then no. It will pass transients as well as the supply current.

Comment: It will pass forward transients as if it wasn't there, but at least it will block the reverse polarity transients, no? I mean, it basically costs nothing (as long as it doesn't get burned).
And thanks for the answer. Your solution is neatly simple. In fact, I thought about the very same thing, but I had no idea if the capacitors will, in fact, do what's expected from them here.

Comment: You're welcome. Just to clear up some of the comments on the OP: the battery is still relevant as it's in circuit when the alternator is running and greatly affects the stability of the vehicle's electrical system. Any circuit schematic would have helped even with a question mark for the part you are unsure of. For example, I added SW1 as I assume you want to switch the device whereas your OP reads as though you will leave 5 V on the input permanently. I had to read several times. The better the question, the less guessing we have to do and, probably, the better the answers you will get.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. The switch you added is exactly right: it's the ignition key switch. And no, I can't just omit the intelligent switch and power my load directly from the ignition switch.     
Asking a good question requires knowing half the answer, they say. And the better you explain which aspect of the question you don't understand, the better I can clarify it! I mean, it's a 2-way road.

Answer (score 0):

Something like an off-the-self voltage regulator like [this one](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf) can produce 5v with an input anywhere from 8-45v, however it may start to get a little toasty at 45v.

In order to protect the regulator from the harsh transient voltages present you should use a TVS(Transient voltage suppression) diode. They come in bidirectional types so if the voltage spikes to high or low they will turn on.Putting it simply they are like a zenzer diode with a fast reaction time.

[Example of such a diode](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Vishay-Semiconductors/P6KE16CA-E3-54/?qs=E3OxquYwg8HxvPtzj4O3Vw%3D%3D)

Comment: I think Violet Giraffe's concern is with voltage transients from, say, the car's starter motor kicking in/out for the 60-100v +/- spikes concern.

Comment: @RobhercKV5ROB: exactly! So no, even if there is a **well-regulated** line somewhere in there, I have no access to it.

Comment: While I don't know a ton about automotive wiring, I would think the 12v source that is present on the cigarette lighter 'jack' already deals with with the transients. Otherwise even things like phone chargers would have to be able to deal that transients.

Comment: @Dave851: no, you would be wrong to assume that, and if you do - your devices would die after some time. And yes, most phone chargers do not account for the automotive specifics, and they die from time to time (not instantly, ofc.). But some chargers actually are designed correctly to withstand the transients.

Comment: My mistake, like I said I don't know to much about cars. There is actually a diode to deal specify with transient voltages however, I'll update my answer in a sec.